# Robot framework: How to use Wait Activity of AppiumLibrary?

Tags: android, robotframework

So, I need to get rid of the dozens of Sleeps I'm using to prevent the test to go too fast causing Robot failing to find things on the screen in time. Just saw there is Wait Activity, Is It usable for the purpose I want? If yes, how?

Description of the command in RF AppiumLibrary paga.

````
Arguments
activity
timeout
interval
=
1

Documentation
Wait for an activity: block until target activity presents or time out.

Android only.

activity - target activity
timeout - max wait time, in seconds
interval - sleep interval between retries, in seconds```
````

Answer (score 0):

you can use some word to reveal the current activity

```
wait activity   sayActivity    3    interval=1
```

[image]

Then you can use the correct activity to wait the seconds that you choose to timeout, the interval determine how often will it check the activity, for example:

```
wait activity   .view.activities.MainActivity    3    interval=1
```